# Cannot use emoji characters or surrogate pairs in xml resources, app crashes

Tags: java, android

I'm building a softkeyboard application which is rendering emojis with the support of corresponding unicodes. On api level 23 and 24, app buids succssfully and renders system emojis without any issue.
Below api level 23, app starts but when the ime start, the application crashes.

I have tried with surrogate pairs. But nothing works. App crashes below api level 23. I noticed that apps built with eclipse renders emojis without issue at api level 21 and 19. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I'm using gradle version 2.2.2 alpha 6 with android studio 2.2 preview 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use emoji.png instead of this.